# chap of chart dose not appropriate amChart

Tags: amcharts, metronic

I use amChart pie to display data with legend boxes in right side

but the text come up box,

Note I use it in metronic design project

this is the picture

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your chart code but try setting `AmCharts.rtl = true;` before any of your chart code is executed to see if that helps first, as it makes the chart more RTL language aware with regards to text placement. You might also need to adjust [`align`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#align), [`valueAlign`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueAlign), 
[`markerLabelGap`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#markerLabelGap), and [`spacing`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#spacing) to fine tune the placement further.